# Fn::ImpotValue not woking in custom ressource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

**Problem:** I'm experiencing a bizarre issue with a `cloudformation` intrinsic function within a  custom resource. When I use `!ImportValue` my template passes and deploys successfully, but if I switch to using `Fn::ImportValue` I get the following error message:

```
Template format error: YAML not well-formed.
```

For completeness the this is the resource in question:

```
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
# Custom Ressources                                                    #
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
LambdaEmptyArtifactBucket:
  DependsOn:
  - ArtifactsBucket
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
  Properties: 
    ServiceToken: !ImportValue util-s3-object-remover-lambda:us-east-1:Lambda:Arn ### <<<--- WORKS
    # ServiceToken: Fn::ImportValue: util-s3-object-remover-lambda:us-east-1:Lambda:Arn ### <<<--- DOES NOT WORKS
    BucketName: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
```

**Question:**
Is there any way of using the long form of `ImportValue` within a custom resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Fn::ImportValue:` should be in a new line or in `{}`:

```
  Properties: 
    ServiceToken: 
       Fn::ImportValue: util-s3-object-remover-lambda:us-east-1:Lambda:Arn
    BucketName: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
```

or

```
  Properties: 
    ServiceToken: {Fn::ImportValue: util-s3-object-remover-lambda:us-east-1:Lambda:Arn} 
    BucketName: !Ref ArtifactsBucket
```